# Date/Time Revit Shared Parameter

Tags: date, time, parameters, revit-api

I am a brazilian student and I work on a research Project where I need to develop plug-ins for Autodesk Revit.
In the midst of my research, some doubts have arisen.
How can I do to insert into a Revit family a shared parameter/project parameter in date/time format ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a string and format it any way you like. Revit parameters do not provide built-in support for date and time.